# Custom Scrollbar with Facebook comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

### The goal

I want to run a scrollbar when a window load within a **Facebook comments'** container.

### The problem

The scrollbar works well, but I have to *resize* the screen to force its invocation.

### The scenario

I made [an example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDUyU/) (take a look!) illustrating the current scenario.

There are two layers:

1. `.comments` — works but you need to resize the window;
2. `.example` — works seamlessly.

So I ask: **someone knows some trick to resolve my problem?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to turn on updateOnContentResize because it is an iframe that gets loaded after the scrollbar has initialised.

```
$(".comments").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme: "dark",
    advanced:{
        updateOnContentResize: true
    }
});
```

Here is the edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vDUyU/1/

Comment: OMFG! Thanks, dude! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad I could help, there are loads of other options here: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

P.S. mark it as the accepted answer if it worked for you

Comment: I was waiting the time to accept the answer, excuse my delay. Thank you again!