# Facebook comment scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

Im building my first website and this is driving me crazy.

no matter what I do the scroll bar is not showing up.

I have tried to use tips from this post: [Custom Scrollbar with Facebook comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657507/custom-scrollbar-with-facebook-comments)

It's still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my website test page. http://www.thespiderkingdom.com/atest.html

Please help or I'm loosing all my hairs.

Comment: 404 for the test page.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i visited your website so If you mean your comment filed does not getting scroll in comment portion.

Then you can just do some tweaks in your css class which is as(fbFeedbackContent  is class in your csss you will find it) :

```
  .fbFeedbackContent 
    {
       max-height: 300px;
       min-height: 160px;
       overflow: scroll;
   }
```

This will do the scrolling just add css to look it good

Answer (score 0):

The element with ID `mCSB_1` gets an inline style with `overflow: hidden;`, I think you should remove it:

```
<div class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-dark" id="mCSB_1" 
    style="position:relative; height:100%; /* overflow:hidden; */ max-width:100%;">
```

And change the `#comment` styling to this:

```
#comment {
    height: 700px; /* If you set this to like 200px you can see the effect better */
    width: 510px;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 380px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**CustomScrollBox**

It might be that `overflow: hidden;` is set by the plugin before the content of the Facebook comments are loaded and the container is still empty.
You can try to (re)initialise the plugin after the Facebook comments are loaded or updated. You can subscribe to all kinds of events as explained on de [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).